# Safari style sheet issue

Tags: wordpress, safari, stylesheet

Ok guys, I have a little news feed/wordpress site going on but no matter what I change, the top H3 tag that houses the month and year, will not change styles in safari. It just doesn't recognize the style. If you open it in any OTHER browser it looks perfectly fine. I'm at a loss and feel that i've changed everything.

here's my css

```
#content h3{
font-size: 13px;
line-height: 18px;
margin-bottom: 5px;
padding: 30px 10px 5px;
border-bottom: 1px solid #ededed;
color: #959595;}
```

and here's the html for it...

```
 <h3 class = "head_style_3"><?php echo  $gttime?> <?php echo $year?></h3>
```

any IDEAS please?! I'm losing my mind...

Comment: Oh and FYI, the link to the site is www.dudnyk.com/news/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right before your statement of `#content h3 {` there is a charset definition in your style.css:

```
@charset "utf-8";
```

Maybe Safari doesn't like that at this position and stops parsing the css but this is only an assumption.

Comment: That was exactly it! Ugh... sometimes you just need fresh eyes. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You're also missing a closing div that will throw the display in some browsers. [[Invalid] Markup Validation of   dudnyk.com news  - W3C Markup Validator](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A//www.dudnyk.com/news/&doctype=Inline&ss=1&group=0&user-agent=W3C_Validator/1.654). Scroll down in the validation report to see line numbers and source code.

And wrap the javascript in CDATA to not have it throw validation errors.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
/* <![CDATA[ */



/* ]]> */
</script>
```